# How to properly use visible binding in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, .net, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want the `.controls` div to be visible only when the value in the textbox is `_OTHER`. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="controls" data-bind="
    visible: title == '_OTHER'
">            
    @Generic.Selection <i data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></i>
    <input type="text" id="inputAnswerContent" data-bind="value: title" />
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-small" data-bind="
        visible: $parent.requireOfferedAnswer, 
        click: $parent.addAnswer
    ">
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

However, it's visible for all values other than `_OTHER`.

Comment: try `$parent.requireOfferedAnswer()` intead of `$parent.requireOfferedAnswer`

Comment: Mind adding a snippet of your Knockout code? There's no way for us to know which values are observable from this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `visible: title() == '_OTHER' (with parentheses).

Simplified example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ExnZ/1/)):

HTML

```
<div class="controls" data-bind="visible: title() == '_OTHER'">            
hello world
</div>
<input type="text" data-bind="value : title"></input>
```

JS

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.title = ko.observable();
}

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Type `_OTHER` in the text box to make `hello world` appear.

Comment: have error Message: TypeError: string is not a function;
Bindings value: visible: title() == '_OTHER'

Comment: @PhongDuong: Sounds like `title` isn't an observable in your view model, is it?  Should it be?/Can you post it?